# How to check if a member has mentioned a specific user?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to check if a member has mentioned/pinged/tagged a specific user, that's it. This is what I've tried:

```js
client.on('message' async message => {

const vips = [<@(someid)>] 

if(message.content.includes(vips){

(the rest of my code) 

}


});
```

Comment: What do you mean? Are you listening for mentions of that specific user? or are you trying to get previous instances where that specific user was mentioned?

Comment: I'm trying to listen for mentions of that specific user. Example: So if a random member mentions me, i can add a role to the member who mentioned me.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? if so, could you show your code?

Comment: Also, which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Question updated and I'm using the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.mentions.users.some((user) => user.id === USER_ID)) {
    message.member.roles.add(ROLE_ID)
  }
})
```